# Dynamic Arrays in VBA/Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've been looking around StackOverflow, but can't seem to find an answer for this question. I'm trying to implement some formulars for minimum variance portfolio calculations in finance. I'm trying to do this in VBA.

Right now, i'm trying to build a simple function that takes a vector as an argument, and concencate this with a 1-vector (i.e. the result will be an array with n rows and 2 columns). The idea is, that i want to be able to take input of any length and still have a working function.

```
[ mu1  1 ]
[ mu2  1 ]
[ mu3  1 ]
```

I've been trying different coding solutions, but none of them seems to work. The issue lies with dynamic arrays i believe. Heres my code

```
        ' MIN VARIANCE CALCULATIONS AND CAPM
Public Function MuConc(mu As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Long
Dim temp() As Variant

For i = 1 To UBound(mu)
    ReDim Preserve temp(1 To i, 1 To 2)
    temp(i, 1) = mu(i)
    temp(i, 2) = 1
Next i
MuConc = temp
End Function
```

Since Redim within a loop is very performance intensive, i've also tried

```
       ' MIN VARIANCE CALCULATIONS AND CAPM
Public Function MuConc(mu As Variant) As Variant

Dim i,n As Long
n = ubound(mu)
Dim temp() As Variant
ReDim temp(1 to n, 1 to 2)


For i = 1 To n
    temp(i, 1) = mu(i)
    temp(i, 2) = 1
Next i
MuConc = temp
End Function
```

Can anyone see what is wrong? Mu is the vector to be concencated with a 1-vector. Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you trying to use the Function?

Comment: Just using it manually in a spreadsheet, As in mark 3 cells, use The funktion and then shift , ctrl Enter for array calc

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing wrong. I wrote the following test and it works fine:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim mu() As Variant
    Dim i, j
    ReDim mu(1 To 5)
    mu(1) = 1
    mu(2) = 2
    mu(3) = 3
    mu(4) = 4
    mu(5) = 5
    mu = MuConc(mu)
    i = 0
    i = i + mu(1, 2)
    i = i + mu(2, 2)
    i = i + mu(3, 2)
    i = i + mu(4, 2)
    i = i + mu(5, 2)    ' i is now 5
    j = 0
    j = j + mu(1, 1)
    j = j + mu(2, 1)
    j = j + mu(3, 1)
    j = j + mu(4, 1)
    j = j + mu(5, 1)    ' j is now 15
End Sub

Public Function MuConc(mu As Variant) As Variant

Dim i, n As Long
Dim temp() As Variant
n = UBound(mu)
ReDim temp(1 To n, 1 To 2)


For i = 1 To n
    temp(i, 1) = mu(i)
    temp(i, 2) = 1
Next i
MuConc = temp
End Function
```

Comment: That is weird. Works for me as well. However, the function still doesn't work when i try to use it on an array in my spreadsheet..

Comment: Please post the code that works on the array in the spreadsheet - maybe you should read the "array" (cells) into an array, operate on that and then write it back to the spradsheet.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Instead of using ubound(mu) i saved the size of the mu-vector with the range.Rows.Count function. The resulting code is

```
Public Function MuConc(mu As Variant) As Variant

Dim i, n As Long
Dim temp() As Variant
n = mu.Rows.Count
ReDim temp(1 To n, 1 To 2)


For i = 1 To n
    temp(i, 1) = mu(i)
    temp(i, 2) = 1
Next i
MuConc = temp
End Function
```

This takes the range "mu" as input, add a column of 1's to it, and output's the resulting 'matrix'.

Thanks for the help anyways guys